# jquery getJSON IP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert the following code to work with jquery:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  req.open('GET', 'http://jsonip.appspot.com', true); 
  req.onreadystatechange = function (e) { 
    if (req.readyState === 4) { 
      if(req.status === 200) {
        var ip = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        alert(ip.address);
      } else { 
        alert("Error loading page\n"); 
      }
    } 
  }; 
  req.send(null);
```

This the jquery piece that doesn't work:

```
  $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com",
        function(data){
             alert( "Data Returned: " + data.ip);

        });
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `data.address`?

Comment: Both should work, since the server returns a JSON array with the "id" and "address" keys.

Comment: You should check the server side code, the problem must com from there. An error 500 is returned when using .getJSON.

Comment: The reason it's not working is because you can't just do JSON calls to any host from anywhere - it's dangerous and it's fortunately not allowed. You will have to do a JSONP callback, see CMS's response for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This host supports [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) custom callbacks, so you can get the result by:

```
 $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
    function(data){
       alert( "Data Returned: " + data.ip);
  });
```

Check the above code [here](http://jsbin.com/eteda).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?', function(data) { 
    console.log( data.ip ); 
} );
```